# Add class for all fallback links

Tags: wordpress, wpml

We using for all not translated atricles/news fallback to default language.
How do for all posts links (and  tag block) add custom class to define this links? I want create for not yet translated articles label, example "Available only EN language".

I think this very easy way... Required only add class to all links if it is thats "fallbacked". But how with WPML?

Comment: You want links to non-existent translations to have a special CSS class?

Comment: Yes, it'll be enough. If links without translations be with additional class